# Json in a partial view called will not fire a second time. MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I have 2 views that are using the same partial view. The first time that the partial loads, the json will fire and everything works great. but when the user moves to the second view the json will not fire.
I tried setting the  [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "noCache")] for the partial, but that didn't work.

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Thanks
Mel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... my problem was a by product of a syntax error. The json performed just fine when I fixed the error.

Comment: You can mark this answer as the question answer now to make this question marked as answered.